# How can I iterate through an array of JButtons to check if a button has been pressed in a Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, actionevent

I'm trying to make a card game in Java GUI, and I can't figure out how to iterate through the player's hand to check if a card in the hand has been pressed. When I press one of the buttons in handButtons, all it does is print "a" about a dozen times, but never enters the if statement.
(Update: I fixed it. I just moved my code to be outside of the (e.getSource() == startButton) heading)

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{   
    int pIndex; 
    if (e.getSource() == startButton)
    {
        pIndex = whoGoesFirst();
        Trick t = new Trick(players[pIndex], cardsInTrick);
        for (int p = 0; p < NUM_OF_PLAYERS; p++) // Goes through all players' turns
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < handButtons.length; i++) // Goes through all cards in the hand 
            // (handButtons is an array of JButtons)
            {
                System.out.println("a"); 
                // When I run this, it prints "a" a lot of times, but never "b" or "c"
                if (e.getSource() == handButtons[i]) 
                {
                    System.out.println("b");
                    if (t.isLegal(players[pIndex], players[pIndex].getHand().get(i)))
                    {
                        System.out.println("c");
                        trickCardSlots[pIndex].setIcon((ImageIcon) handButtons[pIndex].getIcon());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: If `e.getSource() == startButton` is TRUE, then only it will go in the if-block, and after printing 'a', you are checking if `e.getSource() == handButtons[i]` - this is not going to be TRUE ever, as source is `startButton`, then only it went into the if block, and executed the loop. When you press the handButton, the first IF, source == startButton will be FALSE, and won't go in the if block at all, won't execute the for loop, and no other conditions will be checked.

Comment: Remember, each click on the button calls `actionPerformed` afresh with ActionEvent object having the source button which you clicked. So, handlers for StartButton and HandButtons should be separate. You should have two separate `actionPerformed` implementations or there should be 2 parallel if conditions to determine which button is clicked, not nested - hand inside start.  If start is false, hand will never be checked in your case.

Comment: If each card is linked to a button press, why is not each button having the same `ActionListener` added to it?

Comment: In that case (single actionListener for all buttons), there should be 2 parallel ifs.. ```if(source == start) { ... all logic for start ... } else { for (all hand buttons) { if (source == hand[i]) { ... ith hand handler ... break; } } }```.  Not if inside if.